# Why does .AsParallel() hang when run inside a Task?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

In the following simplified code, I spawn 200 Tasks. Each task needs to go through a critical region guarded by a lock. Inside the lock is a .AsParallel() statement. When I run the program, nothing happens. The program hangs indefinitely and nothing is printed.

```
private static object lockObject = new object();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunTasks();
}

private static void RunTasks()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(PerformComputations));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

private static void PerformComputations()
{
    // Computations

    lock (lockObject)
    {
        // The actual operations performed here are irrelevant. The key is that they use .AsParallel()
        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 500).AsParallel().Select(i => i))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

    // Additional computations
}
```

However, everything runs normally (though slowly) if RunTasks is implemented like so:

```
Parallel.For(0, 200, i =>
{
    PerformComputations();
});
```

Everything also works if I remove the .AsParallel() statement from PerformComputations.

Questions:

1. Why does the original code lock up?

   - My best guess is that RunTasks spawns 200 tasks, which is more than the number of physical cores on my machine. The lock statement in PerformComputations ensures all but one task is blocked. When the unblocked thread runs the parallel query, it queues another task. However, the maximum number of active tasks are already active, so the new task sits idly in the queue forever.
   - Is this accurate? Can anyone point me to documentation that would confirm this or explain in more detail?
2. Why doe the modified version of RunTasks work?

   - Is it just that Parallel.For queues less than the maximum number of active tasks?
3. Is there a way to write PerformComputations in such a way that it will work with the original RunTasks method but still run in parallel?

Comment: Part of me would guess that 500 dumps to console get queued really quickly, so, by doing a for loop, effectively within a few ms that whole performcomputations is done, it just takes longer for the console to scroll..   whereas because you parallell start the tasks in your revised thing it may seem more random becuase some tasks actually do start at the same time, rather than one after the other, when they maybe had time to finish before the next started completely?

Comment: In the original code, no thread ever gets to the Console.WriteLine statement. If I place a breakpoint on that line, it is never hit, the application just continues to run indefinitely with no CPU usage. This is not the case with the modified code.

Comment: You should probably avoid blocking code in tasks altogether, and instead of using `Task.WaitAll` you should use `Task.WhenAll` or the new async/await syntax to specify what should happen when all those subtasks complete.

Comment: This test doesn't show any difference between Task.StartNew and Parallel.For. You'll find that a simpe loop without Tasks will run as fast as the first version. Both versions are bad for various reasons, eg `lock` means that only one task can run at a time, making parallelization meaningless.

Comment: Given that you *don't* have any method running in parallel at this point, you could get parallelization simply by cleaning up the code. Each individual method works, if you remove the lock. Eg. using *only* AsParallel. Using *only* Parallel.For*. Starting all tasks at once, although *this* would be slower in a real scenario due to thrashing

Comment: The code I provided is simplified down from the original, not all of which I control. I agree there's no point to the parallelism or the lock in the version I provided. In the original, a great deal happens outside the lock and the locked code runs only once. I'll update the example to clarify this. The questions still apply either way, though.

Comment: Is this running on a windows 10 machine? There is a possibility of a deadlock within Console.WriteLine that only occurs on windows 10.

Comment: Execution never reaches Console.WriteLine, so any problems inside that method wouldn't affect things.

Answer (score 0):

Your are absolutely correct in your answers to questions #1 and #2.

To answer #3: You can specify TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning when you create your tasks. According to the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx this will provide a *hint* to the task scheduler that an additional thread might be required for the task so that it does not block the forward progress of other threads or work items on the local thread-pool queue.

In effect, this makes the task system ignore the ThreadPool and just give you a new, dedicated thread for your task.

Comment: The lock forces all versions to work synchronously. Changing the options won't change this.

Comment: No, but it will allow the AsParallel call from the thread that has the lock to run work on the threadpool, since it is not filled with requests from the task factory.

Comment: Both PLINQ and Parallel use the ThreadPool. Both generate tasks. Both will start with as many tasks as there are cores, partition the data and feed it to them - no need to generate *more* Tasks than can be executed. The assumed difference here is caused because Task.Start creates 200 Tasks at once, that then have to execute sequentiall. Parallel though breaks the 2000 iterations in batches and assigns them to tasks,  that still have to execute sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

The Parallel.For and .ForEach methods, as well as the System.Collection.Concurrent namespace really make your life easy to handle this kind of problem. The scheduler handles the thread management for your according to process priority, system workload, number of cores, etc... Parallelism made easy:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunTasks();
    }

    // This sets up the parallel scheduler to use UP TO 16 simultaneous threads. In reality the thread
    // workload is managed by the CLR according to how many logical threads you have available on your
    // processor.
    private static readonly ParallelOptions _po = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16 };

    private static void RunTasks()
    {
        // Run 200 instances of PerformComputations in parallel. 
        Parallel.For(0, 200, _po, i => PerformComputations());
    }

    private static void PerformComputations()
    {
        // If you want to run the 500 iterations in parallel (sequence is not important),
        // use a concurrent collection. This needs absolutely no lock, the collection is
        // partitioned internally to avoid having to lock. Same goes if you need to share
        // data between multiple runs of PerformComputations(), declare a static bag at 
        // class level.
        var theBag = new ConcurrentBag<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 500));
        Parallel.ForEach(theBag, _po, i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        });

        // Otherwise you don't need a lock at all anyway since each element here is treated
        // one at a time in sequence.
        var theList = Enumerable.Range(0, 500).ToList();
        foreach (var i in theList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct - the original code locks up in the parallel part of `PerformComputations`.

`LongRunning` forces the creation of an entirely new non-thread pool thread (tells the scheduler to create a new thread for the task). Note: you can potentially create many threads causing issues like memory overhead and switching overhead.

```
private static void RunTasks()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLoops; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(PerformComputations, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Interesting read: [Parallelism in .NET](http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/)

To answer Question 3: If you don't mind creating multiple threads (using `Parallel.For`) vs combining the result (`AsParallel().Select`).

```
private static void PerformComputations()
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 500, i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The lock in PerformComputations will force all methods to execute sequentially. The only difference is how blocking is caused by each one.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't understand why are you trying to use `AsParallel()`. If you have 200 mostly independent `Task`s, that should be plenty enough to fully utilize your CPU. This is especially confusing since the only operation that `AsParallel()` executes in parallel is the useless `Select()`.

Now, to actually answer your questions:

> My best guess is that RunTasks spawns 200 tasks, which is more than the number of physical cores on my machine.

The number of cores is not that relevant. The number of threads available is more important. And TPL uses the `ThreadPool`, which has limit on the number of threads created per second also a hard limit on the total number of threads. If you reach the first limit, your code might slow down to a crawl (and *appear* to not do anything). If you reach the second limit, you code would actually deadlock and stop working.

The first limit is not configurable or well documented, [the second limit is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads).

In any case, reaching either of these limits indicates that your code is badly designed when it comes to parallelism.

> Why doe the modified version of RunTasks work? Is it just that Parallel.For queues less than the maximum number of active tasks?

Yes, `Parallel.For` uses smaller number of `Task`s, since that's more efficient.

> Is there a way to write PerformComputations in such a way that it will work with the original RunTasks method but still run in parallel?

I don't understand why would you want to do that. Like I already said before, I don't think running the `Select()` in parallel makes any sense.